# How to solve Could not find com.yanzhenjie:permission:2.0.3.?

Tags: java, android

I was studying Android Studio and I got this error and I can't proceed. Please help me

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.yanzhenjie:permission:2.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/yanzhenjie/permission/2.0.3/permission-2.0.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/yanzhenjie/permission/2.0.3/permission-2.0.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================
```

If you click on the link, you'll get 404 error

Gradle version is 8.2.2
Java version is 8

I was trying to create an app that wanted to represent my location and automatically give the "MainActivity.java file" risk permission.

Comment: The error means that you tried to use a library that doesn't exist on Maven Central nor on the Google Android Maven repository (or whatever it's called). You need to find out on which Maven repository this library is hosted, and add the right repository to your Gradle configuration.

Comment: Maybe you should try version 2.0.2, which does seem to be [hosted on Maven Central](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.yanzhenjie/permission).